# How do I go about upgrading existing Azure VM with Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012, azure, windows-server-2012-r2

Specifically for Azure VM. What is the recommended way to upgrade from Server 2012 VM to Server 2012 R2 on the same VM?

I prefer not to have to create a new 2012 R2 VM and really rather upgrade my existing Server 2012 as I have installed different software on it and configurations.

This question was also asked last year per http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/15e8a17d-0004-4337-a74d-1aa47df4e92d/server-2012-r2-upgrade?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows and remains unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

In-place upgrades of Azure VMs are not supported by Microsoft.

Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2721672

> Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of a
>   Microsoft Azure virtual machine. Instead, you should create a new
>   Azure virtual machine that is running the supported version of the
>   operating system that is required and then migrate the workload.

I realise this might not be all that helpful, but since the Microsoft support position on this wasn't mentioned here, I thought it important to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

There is no recommended way. If you prefer an in-place update, do it. If you prefer the migration-approach, do it.

My personal preference is to rebuild the machine, because I have a "clean" machine again afterwards, but this is personal preference. Especially if you might have had troubles with the VM in the past.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Could you give me any indication how to do an in-place upgrade ? I could not find documentation on a specific step by step.

Comment: Put in CD/Mount ISO. Press Upgrade. Plug in Key. Wait X minutes. Done. :)

Comment: I don't think a CD works since this is an Azure VM. Is it not possible to download an upgrade and install so it overwrites the old one ? If so, I'd appreciate the link.

Comment: Yes, use the normal Windows 2012 R2 download (it's an ISO), mount it on the 2012 Computer, and start the upgrade.

Comment: @JulieS. did you ever try this? Did it work??

Comment: No. I opted to start a new VM in Azure that already comes with R2.